# Remove Config Lines on ASA with Ansible

Tags: ansible, asa

I have an ansible playbook that creates a network object and sets ACL policies. It's working well, but I would like to create the complementary playbook to remove the object and its associated config but I don't know the correct way to approach the task.

I could just use `asa_command` to issue the 'no' prefix for the appropriate lines, however, that doesn't feel like the "Ansible Way" since it would try to execute the commands even if they were already absent in the config.

I have seen that some modules have a `state: absent` operator. However, the `asa_` modules don't indicate that as an option.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: So my assumption that I could use `asa_command` was incorrect. You cannot run config commands as `asa_command` operates in exec mode. You also cannot run `config t` from there as it tells you to that you should use `asa_config` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think having a `state: absent` option makes a lot of sense, as I don't think there is a simple way of doing this more efficiently with the current `asa_` modules. The Ansible team is extremely responsive to issues and PRs, so I would submit one for this feature.

Comment: Thanks Derek, I have submitted that as a request!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there isn't a clean way to do this as of Ansible 2.4. I have  a working playbook, however, I had to settle for issuing the `no` commands using `asa_config` and putting `ignore_errors: yes` in for each play. It's inelegant to say the least and in some cases can break down. I think there may be a way to use an error handling along with `check_mode: yes`. My initial attempt at this failed because when registering the result of a play to a variable, I cannot use that variable to interpret which of the affected hosts actually required a change it's just a generic yes/no for the entire play.

What I'm doing currently:

```
- name: Remove Network Object
  asa_config:
   commands:
    - no object network {{ object_name }}
   provider: "{{ cli }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: dno
```